# when press enter submit fires 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when press enter submit fires 2 times,but click on submit fires one time only,any idea why submit fires 2 time when enter is pressed ?.please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function loadchat() {
    $.post('message.php?action=get', function(response) {
      $('#getmsg').html(response);
    });
  }

  $("input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('form').submit();
    }
  });

  $('form').submit(function(t) {
    var msgs = $("input").val();
    t.preventDefault();
    $.post('message.php?action=sent&msg=' + msgs, function() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: this is the reason of two time fire `if (e.which === 13) {....}`

Comment: If the `input` wrapped by `form`, Enter will send the form. So you send it again..

Comment: try to remove '      $('form').submit(); ' in '$("input").keyup' callback

Answer (score 1):

Check snippet its working fine same as your code
some other code maybe attaching event with it

but if you don't find any thing then use this to avoid double submit

```
$("input").unbind('keyup').bind('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you
Thanks

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

    function loadchat() {
      $.post('message.php?action=get', function(response) {
        $('#getmsg').html(response);
      });
    }

    $("input").keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form').submit();
      }
    });

    $('form').submit(function(t) {
      var msgs = $("input").val();
      t.preventDefault();
      alert(msgs);
      document.getElementById("myform").reset();
      return false;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="he"/>
</form>
```